# Unable to delete *.fs file in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos

I installed Tuxera ntfs a while back and now i am unable to delete one of its files, i wanted to completely uninstall tuxera ntfs so i decided to search tuxera on finder and deleted whatever came along however one file isnt deleting. tuxera_ntfs.fs located at /Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Filesystems/tuxera_ntfs.fs in my mac, i also tried running

```
rm -rf /Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Filesystems/tuxera_ntfs.fs
```

in terminal it also doesnt work
[Terminal error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxdjG.png)
it shows operation not permitted please help, as i encounter such things very often

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it has been awhile from your question, I faced the same problem today and found this answer to be working: [What is /Library/StagedExtensions for and how to remove extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46535279/what-is-library-stagedextensions-for-and-how-to-remove-extensions)

Outline: the kernel provides a new way to clear staged extensions with the following command:

```
sudo kextcache --clear-staging
```

That will wipe the entire "StagedExtensions" directory and any subdirectories.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! (Working on Big Sur).

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo`:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Filesystems/tuxera_ntfs.fs
```